# Getting Wrong Result Set when Using != on Dates in MySQL Exercises

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm doing a sql exercise that says:

**Write a SQL statement to display either those orders which is not issued on date 2012-09-10 and issued by the salesman whose ID is 505 and below or those orders which purchase amount is 1000.00 and below.**

Well, when I look at my query vs. the correct answer they seem parallel in logic, but I'm getting the wrong result set. Can anybody help me understand why my query would be wrong?

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE
((ord_date != '2012-09-10' AND salesman_id <= 505) OR
purch_amt <= 1000);
```

Correct answer:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE NOT
((ord_date = '2012-09-10' AND salesman_id > 505)
OR purch_amt > 1000.00);
```

Below first is a screen capture of my result set, followed by the correct result set. I understand how my result set is wrong, I just don't understand why my query would get that info.

[image: This is the result I get]

[image: This is the correct result set]

Comment: you are wondering why are you getting salesman_id > 505 in your result even if you have it filtered ?

Comment: In your exercise there are 3 conditions to be incorporated . so you should also clarify which two are together (1,2) or (2,3) .

Comment: Your query is correct about `<= 1000`. What is the original language & phrasing of the question? Because the English is ambiguous re "is not ... and" and it uses "either ... or" incorrectly.

Comment: I don't see how your answer is wrong -- if that is all there was to the question and such wording had never been made clear in the past -- the English is not clear.

Comment: Please give input when you give output. If the original assignment was in English then please give it *exactly* and if translated then please put parenthesis into the English to show how it parses in the original language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query,

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE
((ord_date != '2012-09-10' AND salesman_id <= 505) OR
purch_amt <= 1000);
```

you get row with ord_no 70007 because purch_amount (948.5) < 1000 is TRUE and the other condition is FALSE. so TRUE or FALSE evaluates to TRUE and the row is returned.

you get row with ord_no 70009 because purch_amount (270.65) < 1000 is TRUE and the other condition is FALSE. so TRUE or FALSE evaluates to TRUE and the row is returned.

Based on the correct answer,

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE NOT
((ord_date = '2012-09-10' AND salesman_id > 505)
OR purch_amt > 1000.00);
```

the `where` condition is equivalent to 
`(ord_date != '2012-09-10' OR salesman_id <= 505) AND purch_amt <= 1000.00` because of `NOT`. And you can verify the conditions with the data as explained above.

The answer can also be expressed as

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE ord_date != '2012-09-10' AND (salesman_id <= 505 OR purch_amt <= 1000.00);
```

Comment: The "correct" answer does not reflect the English re purch_amt and the English is ambiguous about the not.

Comment: I see where I messed up with the logic. This answer was good and descriptive. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your query, at the opposite of the correct answer, NOT does not wrap all conditions. Till now, it seems obvious, yes.

But the consequence is that you return **both**:

- all records satisfying the 1st condition (even those _not_satisfying the 2nd one)
- all records satisfying the 2nd condition (even those _not_satisfying the 1st one)

So the resulting set includes not only the expected (for correct answer) records but also those which satisfy only one of the two conditions.

---

EDIT, after reading comments from @Philipxy.

I agree that the formulation of the exercise is somewhat ambiguous.
But I choosed to reason using the said "correct answer", which clearly shows what was needed. On this basis we can understand how the other query fails.